# error: Unable to find trailer dictionary while recovering damaged file

Tags: python, django, pypdf, pikepdf

PyPDF2 fail sometimes with decryption of some PDF files, and I am trying do decrypt them with **pikepdf**
but I am getting this error: **Unable to find trailer dictionary while recovering damaged file**
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix broken PDF document with mutool from MuPDF:

```
mutool clean -d input.pdf output.pdf
```

However, the file might just be broken beyond recovery.